# AngularJS display json by directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have little problem with AngularJS, I wanted to make directive to display json imported from other website, directive working, but it doesnt show anything from angular binds(when i was using this code by just putting it hardway, everything was working).

HTML

```
<div ng-app="docsIsolateScopeDirective">
                    <div ng-controller="Controller">
                        <my-post info="post"></my-post>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

ANGULAR

```
(function(angular) {


'use strict';
angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope','$http','$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
    $http.get(link+'json=get_recent_posts&callback=&count=1').then(function(response, date, contents){
    $scope.contents = response.data.posts;
    $sce.trustAsHtml(contents);
});
  }])
  .directive('myPost', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        customerInfo: '=info'
      },
      templateUrl: 'single-post.html'
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

SINGLE-POST.HTML

```
<article>
<div class="news-container">
    <span class="news-category"><a href="">{{content.categories[0].title}}</a></span>
    <h1 class="news-title">{{content.title}}</h1>
    <span class="news-date">{{content.date}}</span>
    <div class="news-image">
        <img src="{{content.thumbnail_images.full.url}}" />
    </div>
    <!-- .news-image -->
    <div class="news-entry">
        <p ng-bind-html="content.content">{{content.content}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

You save your response as

```
$scope.contents = response.data.posts;
```

And you pass into directive variable `post` . Maybe you should pass `contents`  ?

And also in your directive you have `customerInfo` not `content`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `customerInfo` in the template `single-post.html` and also pass `contents` scope object to your directive

Additionally, Using `trustAsHtml()` method correctly.

```
$scope.contents = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.posts);
```

Here is a simplified example:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.contents = {
          title: "test"
        };
      }
    ])
    .directive('myPost', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          customerInfo: '=info'
        },
        template: '<article>\
    <h1 class="news-title">{{customerInfo.title}}</h1>\
</article>'
      };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="docsIsolateScopeDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <my-post info="contents"></my-post>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

its always better to use jsonp for calls to outer domains.
Can you try doing this?

$http.jsonp('some/trusted/url', {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'})

Whitelisting urls is also apt.

Answer (score 0):

Pass $scope.contents to info.

```
 $scope.contents = response.data.posts;

<div ng-app="docsIsolateScopeDirective">
                    <div ng-controller="Controller">
                        <my-post info="contents"></my-post>
                    </div>
                </div>
```